# OpenCV - IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

What is `IplImage` in `OpenCV`? Can you just explain what is meant by it as a type? When should we use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Based on the 'c++' tag you have in your question: 
**You should not use it, you should use cv::Mat.** Every IplImage is a cv::Mat internally.

IplImage is only used in the C API. It is a kind of CvMat and holds image data. Its name originates from OpenCV's roots (Intel IPL).

It is not relevant anymore if you use the C++ API of OpenCV.

Answer (score 23):

IplImage and cv::Mat are different header types for matrix/image data. They're basically compatible with each other, but IplImage is used in OpenCV's C API, while cv::Mat is used in the **new** C++ API.

When you decide to use OpenCV's C API, you will mostly use IplImages. Otherwise you will mostly use cv::Mats.

Of course, you can convert IplImages and cv::Mats to each other, e.g.

```
cv::Mat mat(myIplImage);
```

In this case, they share the same underlying data, i.e. modifications made through either header will be visible regardless of what header you're using to access the data.

Deep-copy (not only header is "transformed"/copied, but also the underlying data) is possible with

```
cv::Mat mat(myIplImage, true)
```

Note that multiple IplImages can also point to the same underlying data, as can multiple cv::Mats.

---

When working with OpenCV and similar libraries it is important to notice that cv::Mats and IplImages are only "headers" for the actual data. **You could say that cv::Mats and IplImages are basically pointers plus important *meta information* like number of rows, columns, channels and the datatype used for individual cells/pixels of the matrix/image.** And, like real pointers, they can reference/point to the same *real* data.

For example, look at the definition of IplImage: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#iplimage

The most important member is `char *imageData;`. This pointer references the *actual* image data. However, the IplImage *as a whole* contains meta information about the image as well, like number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

The IplImage structure was inherited from the Intel Image Processing Library, in which the format is native. OpenCV only supports a subset of possible IplImage formats, as outlined in the parameter list above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are usin C++ you don´t use IplImage because this only use in a C program, (IplImage is in C API).
In addition if you are usin C you need post Cv before the variables names: "CvMat ***" "CvPoint** " "IplImage **" etc. 
It ´s better to use C++ code, you don´t use Cv: "Mat ***" etc. but you can´t use the IplImage type, instead of IplImage you use a Mat type for example in findchessboardcorner function.