# how to write python sys.stdout.write in cpp

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I am working on **opencv with c++**
I got a reference of code written in python [**(reference)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825173/pipe-raw-opencv-images-to-ffmpeg)
I just want to know how to write this line in **c++**

```
sys.stdout.write( frame.tostring() )
```

Please specify the header if needed

---

**HELP**

I got the conversion of python code to c++ **BUT**
But Its popping out me an error saying
I am using **Opencv2.3**

```
error: ‘struct _IplImage’ has no member named ‘tostring’
```

Comment: I suggest you read more about the basics of C++ before trying something more complicated like OpenCV. For example, you might want to check out the `std::cout` object...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the suggestion...I appreciate that but I am already working on opencv for last 3 months.....I made a good progress but had only explored c++ up to the extend i needed it in opencv...
Its very urgent though....Please help me out with a way bro....

Comment: About your second problem, maybe it's called `ToString()` or `toString()`. Use your IDE's autocomplete function to find out the `_IplImage` method that converts it to string.

Comment: I had checked the documentation for both Opencv 2.3 and Opencv 2.1....It was there present in Opencv 2.1 as tostring but not in Opencv 2.3...How do I write my own....
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_basic_structures.html#iplimage
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#iplimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to the standard output (which is what [`sys.stdout`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.stdout)`.write` does in Python) is generally done via the [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) stream and the `<<` operator:

```
std::cout << frame.tostring();
```

Include the `<iostream>` header. The `cout` object is a descendant of [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), so you can do all the things with it that the documentation says you can do with an `ostream`.

---

You can also use C-style I/O. The [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) and [`puts`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/puts) functions (in the `<cstdio>` header) will write a string to standard output:

```
std::printf("%s", frame.tostring().c_str());
std::puts(frame.tostring().c_str()); // also writes '\n' afterward
```

Here I'm assuming your `tostring` function returns a `std::string`; the C-style functions only print null-terminated `char` pointers, not `string`, so I call [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). The `<<` operator, on the other hand, is overloaded to handle most of the common C++ types, so you can print them without calling extra functions.

Comment: Thank you very much....Great response...But when I am using it in Opencv I am getting such error....`error: request for member ‘tostring’ in ‘frame’, which is of non-class type ‘IplImage*’`

Comment: I know nothing about OpenCV. I answered the question title, which was about how to read Python. I assumed since you've been using OpenCV for three months already that you'd know how to do that part. Apparently, you shouldn't be using `IplImage*` directly. [Instead, use `cv::Mat`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5192612/33732) Then you can [use the `<<` syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7971568/33732) like I described.