# Specifying the pointer when copying with OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm having an image memory that I stocked and saved it in a pointer to not loose its address.

I would like now to assign it to an IplImage by the following function **memcpy** (what I have tested):

```
IplImage* img=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_16U, 1);
VOID* ImgMem;
memcpy(img->imageData, ImgMemory, (640*480));
```

It really doesn't work. It stated `Unhandled exception at 0x001b96dd in ex4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000044`.

Any idea how to deal with that?

Comment: I'm no expert in OpenCV, but I'm assuming you're supposed to have allocated space for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is 640x480, but you copied 916x916 pixals.

Comment: Have you allocated memory for ImgMemory? that is a second problem in your program.

Comment: Your ImgMemory is just an empty pointer without any memory allocated for it.

Comment: but there are some memories which are directly allocated without coding right?

Comment: when you declare VOID* ImgMem; your program only allocate a (maybe)64 byte to this pointer only, you need to (char*) malloc(size*sizeof(char)) to allocate memory on the heap; If you just declare char array[size]; then the memory is directly allocated on the stack.

Comment: @TianyunLing Skip `malloc` and skip `new`. Use `std::vector` and go about your merry way.

Comment: That problem reminds me that IpiImage is before opencv 2.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192578/opencv-iplimage

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code. The first issue is you are not initializing 'ImgMem'.

```
VOID* ImgMem;
//    ^^^^^^ Points to whatever
```

If you need to use a buffer prior to copying the data to the image buffer you need to  allocate memory for it.

```
int bufferSize = 640*480*2;
char* ImgMem = new char[bufferSize];
```

Make sure that you delete the memory once you are done with it or you will end up leaking memory.

```
delete[] ImgMem;
```

A better alternative would be to use `std::vector`;

```
std::vector<char> ImgMem(bufferSize, 0);

memcpy(img->imageData, &ImgMem[0], ImgMem.size());
```

This way the memory is allocated, managed and freed by `std::vector` instead of you having to do it every time.

The second problem is you are trying to copy more memory into the image buffer than it can hold.

```
memcpy(img->imageData, ImgMemory, (916*916));
```

This will copy 839,056 bytes when `img->imageData` can only hold 307,200 bytes (assuming 8bpp).

**[Edit: This answer does not take into account the attributes provided by the `IplImage` structure. This includes size AND alignment which are fairly important here in regards to  `memcpy`. For more information on members of `IplImage` see [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html)]**

Comment: The first problem has been solved.
The second: how to allocate?

Comment: 'ImgMemory' : 'std::vector<_Ty>' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=char
1>          ]

Comment: @user2187476 Made a quick update that should help in your usage of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: dbgdel.cpp expression: block type is valid pHead nBlockUse

Comment: There is no way to delete the Image Memory? If I don't it keeps saving the same image memory when I want to have several images.

Answer (score 0):

pixel type is unsigned short IPL_DEPTH_16U and it is 2 bytes, therefore you need to calculate total byte size accordingly:

```
int totalSize = 640*480*2;
char* ImgMemory = new char[totalSize];
memcpy(img->imageData, ImgMemory, (totalSize ));
```

Comment: The line memcpy(img->imageData, ImgMemory, (totalSize )) is still having problems. It fives me the same problem

Comment: `totalSize` is not calculated correctly. It should be `640*2*480` otherwise you allocate for twice as many lines as the image actually has.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious Sory for miscalculation